# stuck with simple Subqueries

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have 2 tables, first one is named `movie_list` contains the following columns:

- `id`
- `actors`
- `movie_id`
- `imdb_id`
- etc...

The second one named `movie_genre` contains the following:

- `id`
- `movie_id`
- `genre_id`

So I did a simple query like this:

```
SELECT movie_list . * , movie_genre.genre_id
FROM movie_list, movie_genre
WHERE movie_genre.movie_id = movie_list.movie_id
AND movie_genre.genre_id
IN ( 12, 35, 878 )
```

and it works fine.

Now I want to do something on the result of this query, like a simple thing as:

```
SELECT tbl1.movie_id FROM
(SELECT movie_list . * , movie_genre.genre_id
FROM movie_list, movie_genre
WHERE movie_genre.movie_id = movie_list.movie_id
AND movie_genre.genre_id
IN ( 12, 35, 878 ))as tbl1
```

And it doesn't work

I'm stuck, what am I doing wrong with my subquery?

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Don't use the implicit join notation with commas in the FROM list; use the explicit JOIN notation.  It is ultimately much simpler.

Comment: Remove that `as` from `as tbl1`

Comment: @Rahul: I know Oracle doesn't like the SQL standard AS; does MySQL follow the SQL standard or Oracle?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, have never seen using `as` in derived table name but not sure through. OP's query looks ok to me, so thought that may be the issue. Worth trying .. isn't it?

Comment: Using `AS` for a table alias (also known as a correlation name) is an optional but standard part of SQL. For some reason unknown to me, Oracle doesn't support `AS` in that place, even though they support `AS` for column aliases in the select-list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could rewrite your first query using the explicit join notation as:

```
SELECT l.*, g.genre_id
  FROM movie_list AS l
  JOIN movie_genre AS g ON l.movie_id = g.movie_id
 WHERE g.genre_id IN (12, 35, 878)
```

You should then be able to embed this as a sub-query in the FROM clause:

```
SELECT t.movie_id
  FROM (SELECT l.*, g.genre_id
          FROM movie_list AS l
          JOIN movie_genre AS g ON l.movie_id = g.movie_id
         WHERE g.genre_id IN (12, 35, 878)
       ) AS t
```

However, as far as I can see, this is isomorphic with the query you wrote.

You say "doesn't work, get stuck" without explaining what that means.  Saying "doesn't work" is problematic on SO.  When you say "get stuck", do you mean it does not return any data within a reasonable time?  You should clarify what your problem is.

You may need to specify which version of MySQL you are using and the platform you are using it on.

Also, how many rows are there in each of your tables, and where do you have indexes on them?  As long as you have an index on either `movie_list.movie_id` (unique) or `movie_genre.movie_id` (duplicates allowed since movies can belong to several genres at once) or both, you should not run into serious performance problems.

Comment: Well what i meant is  it stuck, no data returns at all, i need to exit my browser and come back again for my phpmyadmin to work

Comment: OK; 'does not return any data in a reasonable time'.  It's worth spelling it out clearly.  Have you looked at the query plans for the original query and the query with the original query as a sub-query?  Frankly, the optimizer should reduce them to the same query plan; if it doesn't that indicates a bug in the optimizer.  And, all of a sudden, the platform and version information becomes more important.  If you're not running a near-to-current version, it may well be time to upgrade.  If you are running a near-to-current version, then life gets trickier.  Table sizes and indexing matter too.

Comment: @user3299182: Thanks for accepting, but I'm a little curious to know why.  Did the explicit join notation work sanely?  Does the implicit join notation still fail?  Or was there something else that made everything work?